# Java: If a java library is not thread safe, does this mean I can't run it in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

So I have this 3rd party java library I am using and in the documentation it says, not thread safe.

However I just ran it in a separate thread from my UI and it ran fine as expected (otherwise the entire app locks up until everything is finished).

So what can I expect now that I am running a non thread safe library in a thread?

update:

could I run each separate threads for each new class instances of this 3rd party library? or does this mean that I can't just use more than one thread per class.

```
Run in thread 1 : ThirdPartyProcessing tpp1 = new ThirdPartyProcessing();
Run in thread 2 : ThirdPartyProcessing tpp2 = new ThirdPartyProcessing();
Run in thread 3 : ThirdPartyProcessing tpp3 = new ThirdPartyProcessing();
```

Comment: (Re: your update, see my answer below)

Comment: Since you're frequently deleting your questions after I've given them consideration, I figure I'm just wasting my time in the effort.  `doNotHelpList.add(Kim Jong Woo);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels cool story bro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-thread safe means that the code does not expect to be called from more than one thread simultaneously. If it is called from two (or more) threads at the same time it will not behave as expected.

In your case you're running it from a single thread, which is fine. It is just no the main thread of the app. No problem with that.

Update

> could I run each separate threads for each new class instances of this 3rd party library? or does this mean that I can't just use more than one thread per class.

There's no definite answer, but usually (non) thread-safety is on an instance-by-instance basis. That is: non-thread safe code does not work well only when two threads access the same instance. Therefore, one thread per instance, as you suggest, will probably work fine.

The only caveat is that sometime libraries maintain some of their mutable state in static fields which can lead to to inter-thread collision even if each thread accesses a dedicated instance. However, in most libraries this is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

> So what can I expect now that I am running a non thread safe library in a thread?

If you run a non-thread-safe application / library exclusively in one thread, then you shouldn't have any problems.

Non-thread-safe means "not safe to run using more than one thread".  So, if you use more than one thread to run it or to access/update its data structures, then bad things *could* happen.  It is not guaranteed that they *will* happen each time you run, and it is not (in general) possible to predict what those bad things are going to be.  However, the possibility always exists.

> could I run each separate threads for each new class instances of this 3rd party library? or does this mean that I can't just use more than one thread per class.

It depends on why the 3rd party library is not thread-safe.  If the each instance of the class is completely independent of the others (i.e. if there is no sharing of data structures between them) then that could work.  On the other hand, if they share stuff (e.g. via a static) then there are likely to be problems.  And in theory those problems could even exist if the shared data is immutable.  (For reference, the problem in the latter case is the problem of "safe publishing".)

The bottom line is that unless you *know* how / why the library is not thread-safe you are taking a risk by trying to run multiple instances in different threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can expect trouble if multiple threads try to use it at the same time.

"Not thread safe" means its internal representation doesn't (properly) handle access from multiple threads. If only a single thread actually *uses* the library, thread safety isn't an issue.